# Is it true that frontend validation is generally redundant for minimalist contact forms on minimalist environments?

Tags: email, javascript, validation, administration, css

Say I have a continuously upgraded and well maintained LAMP environment with a website which its CMS is all-core and continuously upgraded as well and I have created a simple backend HTML contact form which is CMS-agnostic (not a module of the site's CMS) so the overall environment is minimalist and very secured and the contact form is minimalist in these regards:

1. It doesn't store any data in any database existing on the environment
2. It doesn't include fields for any sensitive data (passwords, financial data, etc.)
3. It only has and should always only have the following fields:

   - Name (`input type="text"`)
   - Email (`input type="email"`)
   - Phone (`input type="tel"`)
   - Topic (`<select><OPTIONS></select>`)
   - Preferred day for appointment (`input type="date"`) [exact hour would be set in private because as of 11/03/2021 W3 doesn't offer a combined date && hour-minute field]
   - Notes (`input type="text"`)

### Question

**Is it true that frontend validation is generally redundant for minimalist contact forms on minimalist environments?**

### Notes

- By "frontend validation" I mean solely to CSS/HTML trickiness and not for any HTML-derived special tag behaviors
- I still don't have a mechanism to send a copy of the message to a potential customer but I hope to add one in the future
- I still don't have AJAX/AJAX for a message which indicates that sending was successful but I hope to add one in the future

Comment: Frontend validation is not a security control - it's for convenience ... Is the assumption here that frontend validation is a security control and you feel that it is unnecessary in this context?

Comment: @schroeder this is pretty much the assumption, yes ; indeed for me you only consolidate what Mike Ounsworth said in his great answer ; I thank you both,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that frontend and backend validation are not redundant because they serve different purposes:

- Backend validation: enforcing the data format as it enters the application.
- Frontend validation: reducing user frustration when filling out the form.

If your app needs input validation for some important reason (security, data correctness, etc) than you need to do that on the server and reject input that does not conform (400 Bad Request). Doing validation on the client side should only be about user experience -- for example you can give them a "This is not a valid email address" message in the UI as they are typing -- but should never be relied on because client-side logic won't be respected by tools like curl, or by malicious users who do Edit&Resend in their browser.

So if you can build a reasonable user experience with only server-side validation, then yeah, no need for client-side validation.

Comment: I thank you dearly for the answer ! I find one sentence particularly very interesting: `validation on the client side should only be about user experience` ; that quite proves that at least in the scenario I have presented in my question, I did pretty much everything I can to ensure good user experience (today in 2021 much of that comes from HTML and W3 standards anyway, I think).